# How to manage/list my objects?

Tags: java, arraylist

In my java code I build a few objects of the type **Student**.
--- the object Student contains a String name and an int grade ---
is it possible to list all of my created object with a method?

or rather to list all names of my objects without adding them one by one ?

Comment: you can put those objects in a collection / array, and loop through them to print. we have to see some codes to understand your problem better.

Comment: Please include a [mcve].

Comment: Adding on to @Kent's answer, in your Student class you will need to add a `toString()` method so that they print how you want them to.

Comment: Please share the code with us, what you have started with

Answer (score 1):

Sure, put them all in some collection like an array or a list and iterate over it using for each, calling print on a method that returns the name of a student in the loop.

Code example:

```
List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
students.add(student1);
...
for (Student s : students) {
     System.out.println(s.getName());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I couldn't find my typo which messed up the layout from my phone.

Answer (score 1):

You Can Add the Student Objects into a Collection/Array Then loop through the Collection/Array and print whichever you like.

Here is an Example:

```
public class Student {
    private String name;
    private int grade; 

    public Student(String name , int grade){
        this.name = name;
        this.grade = grade;
    }

    public int getGrade() {
        return grade;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    } 
}
```

A Main Class Example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Creating a list of Student Objects
        ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();    
        students.add(new Student("John",10));
        students.add(new Student("Ahmed",100));
        students.add(new Student("Jonny",10));

        //Printing the name of each student
        for(Student student:students){
            System.out.println(student.getName());
        }
        //Printing the grade of each student
        for(Student student:students){
            System.out.println(student.getGrade());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't advice using non-final, non-private fields. They cause all kinds of trouble when things get slightly more complicated and writing a getter isn't that much work.

Comment: Thanks, I agree with you that applying encapsulation is a great thing, But at some situations It's considered an overkill, especially when it's out of question scope. Anyway, It's a good practice to do, especially most IDEs have auto creation for getters and setters.

Answer (score 0):

> *is it possible to list all of my created object with a method?*

yes, override the `toString` method in the class, then create an List of students

`List<Student> myList =  new ArrayList<Student>();`

and then print them calling `System.out.println(myList );`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that. This should serve as a complete example.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StudentDemonstration {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many student records to create : ");
        int numberStudents = in.nextInt();
        in.nextLine();
        Student students[] = new Student[numberStudents];
        for (int i=0; i<students.length; i++){
            students[i] = new Student();
            System.out.println("Enter name for student " + i + " : " );
            String name = in.nextLine();
            students[i].setName(name);
            System.out.println("Enter grade for student " + i + " : ");
            int grade = in.nextInt();
            in.nextLine();
            students[i].setGrade(grade);
        }
        System.out.println("Printing student details : " );
        for (int i=0; i<students.length; i++){
            System.out.println("Student details " + i);
            System.out.println("Name : " + students[i].name);
            System.out.println("Grade : " + students[i].grade);
        }
        in.close();
    }
}

class Student{
    String name;
    int grade;

    public Student(){
        this.name = null;
        this.grade = 0;
    }

    public Student(String name, int grade){
        this.name = name;
        this.grade = grade;
    }

    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setGrade(int grade){
        this.grade = grade;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks to all of u, who gave me an answer. You were very helpfull